# My Iframe Won't open?

Tags: iframe

I can't open the following page in . Can someone solve why and if you know please send me the code?? https://www.mcjukebox.net/client?server=1792

This is the website.

Comment: Inspect [the response headers](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/zXd7o) of the site and see that it contains `X-Frame-Options: Deny`. They don't want you to embed their content like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead developer of MCJukebox. We intentionally block all embedding of the client as this allows users to place the client on their site but without official support. This could cause issues which are hard for us to work on, and we also prefer users coming onto our domain as the project is made free and we need a way of attracting new users.

Feel free to email us if you have any more issues.